# SQL - Filtering return value when under 100

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, having-clause

I have a stored procedure that is joining on other tables to calculate a percentage which I have called column called  `mp.PrTotal` renamed as `TotalPercentage` that I will be using for a graph. Due to some bad data there are a few of `TotalPercentage` that is greater than 100% which should be returned.

So I am attempting to add a filter on it similar to the logic of `SELECT ... WHERE TotalPercentage is less than or equal to 100`. After attempting a few different iterations of this. I am still returning back the percentages that are greater than 100.

What will be the best way to approach this?

I've attempted to add `WHERE mp.PrTotal <= 100`

Here is an example of my return results:

```
+------------------------------------+
| StateId ProductId   TotalPercentage|
+------------------------------------+
| 1             12           0.21    |
| 1             10         102.34    |
| 1            341          87.30    |
| 1             21          62.1     |
| 1             73         100.32    |
+------------------------------------+
```

My expected out come to return the `TotalPercentage` that is less then 100

For example:

```
    +------------------------------------+
    | StateId ProductId   TotalPercentage|
    +------------------------------------+
    | 1             12           0.21    |
    | 1            341          87.30    |
    | 1             21          62.1     |
    +------------------------------------+
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
select top 10
    StateId,
    ProductId,
    TotalPercentage,
from   
    (select        
         i.StateId,
         i.ProductId,
         sum(PrTotal) as TotalPercentage
     from          
         (select               
              mp.StateId,
              mp.ProductId,
              mpr.PrTotal,
          from
              dbo.MpTotals mp
          where         
              mp.StateId = @StateId
              and mp.ProductId = @ProductId
              and mp.PrTotal <= 100  -- filter attempt
        ) i
    group by             
        i.StateId, i.ProductId, ) 
order by 
    TotalPercentage desc
```

Comment: Might be helpful if you can supply a create table script with some sample data that reproduces the problem - then people can focus on the query.  You want to make it as easy as possible for them to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt fails because you are filtering before grouping, while you want to  compute the `sum()` first, and then filter.

Your query seems much more convoluted than it needs to be. There is no point for these several levels of subqueries. You can select, filter, aggregate, sort and limit without any nesting. To filter on the aggregate result, you can use a `having` clause:

```
select top (10) StateId, ProductId, sum(PrTotal) TotalPercentage
from dbo.MpTotals
where StateId= @StateId and ProductId= @ProductId
group by StateId, ProductId
having sum(PrTotal) <= 100
order by TotalPercentage desc
```

It is unclear what alias `mpr` relates to in your original query (as it stands, that's a syntax error). The query adresses just one table, so I just unqualified all identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a CTE and remove the undesired values from the CTE

*this is just one way of doing it*

```
; with mycte as (

select top 10
                           StateId,
                           ProductId,
                           TotalPercentage,
              from   (

                           select        
                                                i.StateId,
                                                i.ProductId,
                                                sum(PrTotal) as TotalPercentage

                           from          (
                                                select               mp.StateId,
                                                                     mp.ProductId,
                                                                     mpr.PrTotal,
                                                                     
                                                from
                                                                     dbo.MpTotals mp

                                            
                                                where         mp.StateId= @StateId
                                                and           mp.ProductId= @ProductId
                                               
                                                              
                                                ) i
                          
                           group by             i.StateId,
                                                i.ProductId,

                           ) 

)

Select * from mycte 

where TotalPercentage <=100
              order by TotalPercentage desc
```

Another way to do this is to add a HAVING clause to your group by

like this

```
group by            
 i.StateId,
  i.ProductId,

having 

sum(PrTotal) <=100
```